# Why does the download URL from firebase storage return null only on my first request?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Here is the image picker function which works fine.

```
//Function runs when the submit button is pressed and an image is selected
   const pickImage = async () =>{
       try{
           let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
               mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
               allowsEditing:true,
               base64:true,
               aspect: [4,3],
               quality:1
           });
           //URI of the image picked is selected
           const source = result.assets[0].uri;
           //Sets Image to be displayed to the URI
           setImage(source);
           //Sets Is uploading is true
           setUploading(true);
       }catch(error){
           alert("Please try again, no image selected")
           return;
       } 
   };
```

Here is the function that uploads to firebase and tries to get the download URL. The error handlers don't alert me of any errors. Instead, the success alert is always shown. The image always does upload into firebase storage perfectly fine, it's just the getDownloadURL function does not work on the first request

```
const [URI, setURI] = useState([]);
 const handleFirebaseURI = async () =>{
              var metadata = {
                contentType: 'image/jpeg'
              }
              const response = await fetch(image);
              const blob = await response.blob();
              const filename = await image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
             //Reference to Firebase storage, folder created for each user email
            const imageRef = ref(storage, `${user.email}/${Date.now() + filename}`);
            //Uploads Image to Firebase Storage
            await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, blob, metadata).then( async (snapshot) => {                    
                            //using imageRef instead causes same error
                  await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(async (url) =>{
                        setURI(url)
                        alert("Success")
                  }
                  //getDownloadURl error catch
                 ).catch((error)=>{
                  alert(error)
                 });
                 //uploadBytes error catch
                }).catch((error)=>{
                  alert(error)
                })
            }
```

Here is the function that uses the fetch API to post to the server

```
 const fetchReq = async () => {
              const token = user && ( await user.getIdToken());  
              const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
                //URI is the firebase storage download URL
                body: JSON.stringify({propertyAddress,address,addedField,URI,local,user: user.email})
              }
              //Enpoint just logs the request body server side
              fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/ReadInfo', requestOptions)
            }
```

Here is the submit function.

```
 const handleSubmit = async () => {

    await getLocation();
    await handleFirebaseURI();
    //FetchReq is awaited for, after all UI state resets
    await fetchReq();
//State of UI is reset
    setAddress('');
    setAddedField([])
    setNeededInput([])
    setImage(null);
    setUploading(false);
   
   
    
  }
```

Here is what is shown on the server's log.

```
{
  User: 'test@email.com',
  Property: '',
  Reads: [],
  Location: {
    timestamp: 1680540313646,
    mocked: false,
    coords: {
      altitude: 0,
      heading: 0,
      latitude: 37.4220936,
      longitude: -122.083922,
      altitudeAccuracy: 0,
      speed: 0,
      accuracy: 600
    }
  },
//HERE IS THE ERROR, EXPECTED FIREBASE DOWNLOAD URL
  Image_URI: []
}
```

However, if I submit the form again, the image URL is there as expected, it just never works on the first submission.